# Generic block diagonal matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a *square* matrix of size `C` by `C` and I want to build a diagonal block matrix with it repeated `N=2C(1+C)` times. The problem is that the value of `C` can change, and so I don't know if I could use `blkdiag`, as I don't know the number of parameters I should enter because the size of the matrix is a variable that the user chooses. How could I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Why can't you use `blkdiag` with variable parameters?

Comment: @AndrasDeak I don't know how to do it. Is it possible? I've always used  `blkdiag(A,A,A)`, for example. How could I write that without hardcoding the number of matrices?

Comment: [Like this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/295221): construct a cell, then pass that to blkdiag (as a comma-separated list). Of course there might be a more straightforward approach; I admit that I didn't really think your issue through before asking:)

Comment: So I mean something like `tmpcell = repmat({A},[1, 2*C*(1+C)]); out = blkdiag(tmpcell{:})`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
 M = kron(eye(N),A);
```

where `A` is the CxC matrix that repeats `N` times....

Because this will scale rather quickly , for sparse implementation use:

```
M = kron(speye(N),A);
```

Comment: I have a feeling though that this will explode quite quickly and that Tendero needs a different approach (sparse matrices?)

Comment: Well, I guess that all depends on the sizes. But yeah, I can imagine that. Wonder if there's a similarly elegant construction for a sparse array, or one needs to hack around with some `sparse()` index contortion. Edit: Well, `kron` works for sparse matrices, so I guess it could still be fine with sparse inputs.

Comment: Why do you say that it will "explode quite quickly"? (Yes, btw, I _am_ construcing a sparse matrix for an LDPC code)

Comment: @Tendero I think bla meant that your linear size goes with `C^2`, so the number of elements goes with `C^4`, that's quite steep.

Comment: just do `M=sparse(kron(eye(N),A))` instead so you wont run out of memory for the case A and N are big...

Comment: it's the same I think (shorter though so I like it more)